# I get an error unexpectedly contains class .. while obfuscate the war file

Tags: proguard, war, obfuscation

Hi I'm a junior developer, I'm new to Proguard. I am trying to obfuscate since I will use my war file in my standalone web project. I am obfuscate with the proguard task I added the war file to in build.xml. however, the project is receiving an error. these are my interface and database classes and model classes. war file can be obfuscate written. But there are a lot of sources that can not be written.
While looking for the error I received, it redirects to the proguard site and I don't understand the article there. Please guide me.

```
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/db/MyList.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.db.MyList]
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/db/impl/Derby.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.db.impl.Derby]
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/db/impl/Oracle.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.db.impl.Oracle]
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/db/impl/SqlFactory.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.db.impl.SqlFactory]
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/db/interfaces/IDerby.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.db.interfaces.IDerby]
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/db/interfaces/IOracle.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.db.interfaces.IOracle]
[proguard] Warning: class [WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/wab/data/CodeTemplate.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.mycompany.wab.data.CodeTemplate]
 [proguard] Warning: there were 895 classes in incorrectly named files.
 [proguard]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
 [proguard]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
 [proguard]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
 [proguard]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
```

Comment: Did you try this action: "Notably, class files that are in the WEB-INF/classes directory in a war should be packaged in a jar and put in the WEB-INF/lib directory" ?

Comment: When I open the War file with winrar, the Web-INF classes file appears. Do I have to make them jar?